How to dynmically Register a explicit broadcast from a foreground service?
Using Android 14.
As per my understanding Broadcast receivers for Implicit broadcast can not be registered statically in manifest anymore( except few ) but for Explicit intent It can be done both ways. --> Is this understanding correct?
I have a foreground service which shows a persistence notification.
It has a custom broadcast receiver class. The idea is to be able to send broadcast using pendingIntent when the notification is manually swiped off by the user.
Below code is how I am setting the pending intent.
val notficationRemovedIntent = Intent(applicationContext,NotificationRemovedReceiver::class.java).apply {
            action=notificationRemovedIntent
        }
    
        val pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(applicationContext,NOTIFICATION_ID,notficationRemovedIntent,
            PendingIntent.FLAG_IMMUTABLE)

val notification = NotificationCompat.Builder(this, "running_channel")
            .setContentTitle("Service running")
            .setSmallIcon(.....)
            .setPriority(NotificationCompat.PRIORITY_MAX)
            .setOngoing(true)
            .setDeleteIntent(pendingIntent)
            .build()
        startForeground(NOTIFICATION_ID,notification,if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.R) {
            ServiceInfo.FOREGROUND_SERVICE_TYPE_SPECIAL_USE
        } else {
            0
        })

Now If i register the broadcast receiver class NotificationRemovedReceiver using manifest.xml it works just as expected
        <receiver
            android:name=".presentation.NotificationRemovedReceiver"
            android:enabled="true"
            android:exported="true">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="COM.SOUMYADIP.OTP_FORWARD.NOTIFICATION_REMOVED_ACTION"/>
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>

But if I register the reciever in the onStartCommand of the service. It is not working.
override fun onStartCommand(intent: Intent?, flags: Int, startId: Int): Int {

        notificationRemoveReceiver=NotificationRemovedReceiver()
        val notificationRemovedIntentFilter = IntentFilter("COM.SOUMYADIP.OTP_FORWARD.NOTIFICATION_REMOVED_ACTION")
        registerReceiver(notificationRemoveReceiver,notificationRemovedIntentFilter,
            RECEIVER_EXPORTED)

        startForegroundService()
        return START_STICKY
    }

Basically manifest driven registration is working but not dynamically in my Service class.
Note: I have another broadcast receiver for a implicit broadcast like SMS Received Action. Which is being dynamically registered in same Service class. It is working fine.

I would start by not exporting these receivers. If it is your service sending a broadcast to your receiver, you do not need the receiver to be exported. If anything, you should not want the receiver to be exported, as that opens your app up to attack, as anyone in the world can write an app that triggers your receiver. There is no concept in Android of dynamically registering a receiver to respond to explicit Intents -- you can only dynamically register for implicit Intents.
